# "Testification" in US English

Tags: word-choice, grammar, american-english, british-english

> The usage of Dieter Wisclieceny’s statements and testifications from
>   the Nuremberg Trials as the basis for the interrogation and trial of
>   Eichmann is also accurate.

In Microsoft word,  *testifications* is being underlined in red. The spell check language I have is US English. A google of the term reveals that there is indeed a term called *testifications*. It probably is a British English term.

Should I just ignore the red line or is there a replacement word for *testifications*?

As a side question, is there a better way to formulate the sentence above?

Comment: The correct word is *testimony*. "Testifications" sounds more like George W Bush than Winston Churchill.

Comment: @StJohnoftheCross Thats the word I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: @StJohnoftheCross: *Bush* :) LOL. That was funny.

Comment: Another acceptable alternative would be [attestations](http://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&q=attestation&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=eVZGUc7iCNGa0QW69IGwAg&sqi=2&ved=0CC0QkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43828540,d.d2k&fp=c4123f922dd4a43&biw=1251&bih=853) *(the action of bearing witness)*. Not that *testifications* is incorrect "by the book", but it's pretty unusual phrasing for this day & age.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First rule of thumb: ***Microsoft is usually wrong.***  You should seriously consider disabling its nannying.

Certainly *testification* is a word, but per the OED it is now “rare”.  You just want *testimony*.

> ### testification [ˌtɛstɪfɪˈkeɪʃən].
>
> Now *rare*.
>
> Etymology: a. obs. Fr. *testificacion* (1400 in Godef.), or ad. L. *testificātiōn-em*, n. of action f. *testificārī* to testify.
>
> The action or an act of testifying; the testimony borne; a fact or object (as a document, etc.) serving as evidence or proof.
>
> - C. 1450 *Cov. Myst.* vii. (1841) 69 — Wyttnessynge here, be trew testyficacion, That maydenys childe xal be prince of pes.
> - 1593 Abp. Bancroft *Daung. Posit*. i. iii. 10 — A testification was made of their intentes.
> - 1633 Sanderson *Serm*. (1681) II. 30 — Honour..is an acknowledgment or a testification of some excellency or other in the person honoured, by some reverence or observance answerable thereunto.
> - 1640-1 *Kirkcudbr. War-Comm. Min. Bk.* (1855) 42 — That he shall bring..Margaret Sampell’s testification that he is her hired servant.
> - 1671 Flavel *Fount. Life* xi, — Thankofferings, in Testification of Homage, Duty and Service.
> - 1718 Hickes & Nelson *J. Kettlewell* ii. xxxii. 139 — For the perpetual Testification whereof there was an Instrument drawn up.
> - 1865 G. Meredith *Rhoda Fleming* ix, — The thin blue-and-pink paper, and the foreign postmarks-testifications to Dahlia’s journey.

Comment: Although a spell checker with too many obscure words isn't necessarily good. One that allowed 'wether' as a castrated goat is accurate but probably unhelpful

Answer (score 2):

I hadn't heard this word before. Google Books doesn't seem to confirm it either. So if it even existed, it would be very colloquial. I would go with *Testimony*, which according to the OED means:

> *a formal written or spoken statement, esp. one given in a court of law.*

Comment: No, it is not colloquial: it’s old, and now rare.  That verging on the opposite of colloquial.

Answer (score 0):

As for recasting the sentence, I think the following would be better, although the use of the word *accurate* in the original version is a little puzzling to me:

> It is true, the statements and testimony of Dieter Wisclieceny were the basis for interrogating Eichmann at his trial.

Comment: By accurate I mean that it is historically accurate and not a fictional representation. (I am analysing a movie for historical accuracy) That is actually the main point of my sentence so I can't remove that part.

Comment: How about:  To say Dieter Wisclieceny's statements and testimony were the basis for interrogating Eichmann at his trial is accurate historically.